# Research about Stafford Beer's claim about a method for solving simultaneous equations unknowingly via a game by kids?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra, algebra, cybernetics

I found this claim in the book "How many grapes went into the wine", in the Artorga section:

> In 1956 I devised a game for solving simultaneous linear equations in two variables. The theory used the properties of groups to simplify the arithmetic: the game worked in homomorphic transformations modulo 5. It was played by unsophisticated persons, such as children, who could not be expected to know everything about simultaneous equations. They competed with each other to make correct selections from sets of five, and then to synthesize the selections and select therefrom, by means of a simple machine. This simulated algedonic feedback by means of coloured lights which announced that 'pleasure' or 'pain' was being experienced.
> The idea of this was to demonstrate the possibility of intelligence amplification. Intelligence, in the sense of an ability to steer one's way from pain to pleasure within a simple game language, was certainly amplified in that (unknown to the competitors) the equations were actually solved. Was any particular solution implicit in the game language? I think not; because the game could and did handle actual equations which had not been previously studied by the inventor. This series of experiments was entirely successful; unfortunately the opportunity to write them up for publication has now been lost.

Does anybody knows how this could be made (the mechanics of the method of solving the systems) or has any idea about it, and if other similar researches were made (and link material them)?
I'm very curious about it

Comment: HI, can you provide a link to the book online, or at least the author and publisher?

Comment: The book is "How Many Grapes Went into the Wine: Stafford Beer on the Art and Science of Holistic Management" by Allenna Leonard